# the weight of a hose with water passes through it

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, weight

a hose is connected to a water supply at the ground and is held by hand from point B. I want to calculate the tension at point B. but how does the resultant weight (W) of the hose will change if water passes through it?

[image]